# Why doesn’t my Nexus 7 Wifi (2013) auto-update to Lollipop?

Tags: nexus-7, 5.0-lollipop

I just got a new Nexus 7 Wifi (2013). Immediately after first boot, notifications for system updates started appearing. (One for 4.4.3 and another one for 4.4.4.) I’m currently at 4.4.4 but the System Update section of Settings is displaying that the system is up to date.

Why doesn’t the Lollipop update register, and is there anything I can to to make it show up?

Comment: Possibly Google halted and skipped 5.0 due to buggy update in prefer of 5.0.1. As [5.0.1 was released 3 weeks ago](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-android-5.0.1-factory-image-for-nexus-7-9-10-direct-links/), I'd say to wait for few more days. Otherwise, just manually flash the factory image.

Comment: Well, like @AndrewT. said you can wait a bit more while for the update to show up as still the update is on roll out and a number of regions haven't got the update seeded for their device !